Overlaying Plots in MatPlotLib
I am trying to use matplotlib to overlay a bar chart and a line chart on separate axis.
When I run these individually, it works, however when I combine them it doesnt show one of the datasets.
Unsure what I am missing/doing wrong.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Assuming grouped is the name of your DataFrame
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

# Create a bar chart for the number of plates
ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
ax1.set_ylabel('Number of Plates', color='tab:blue')
grouped['NOOFPLATES'].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax1, color=custom_colors)  # Adjust the color as needed

#create a line chart for number of errors
ax2 = ax1.twinx()  
ax2.set_ylabel('Total Errors', color='tab:red')
grouped['ERRORS'].plot(kind='line', ax=ax2, color=custom_colors, marker='o')  # Adjust the color as needed

plt.title('Number of Plates and Total Errors over Time')
fig.tight_layout()  
plt.show()


can you make this a [MCVE]? i.e. make a small dummy version of your grouped dataframe, with similar limits on the data, so others can run your code here

This is a common problem when plotting line and bar graphs in the same ax. The line and bar graphs often have different xticks, even if the data of x-axis is same, and the two graphs with different xticks cannot be plotted on the same ax.

Add some data to this question.

add synthetic data
